# How to handle conditional prepared statements using prisma and postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I have a search query that its parameters changes depending on the client input.

```
await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT column FROM table ${condition ? `WHERE column = '${condition}'`  :' ' } `)
```

how can I write this query using prepared statement and avoiding duplicate queries. The only solution I came up with is the following:

```
const result = condition ? await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = $1`,condition) : await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT column FROM table`)
```

The goal from this is to avoid sql injections from the first query.

**EDIT**
after trying the solution suggested by @Ryan I got the following error:

```
Raw query failed. Code: `22P03`. Message: `db error: ERROR: incorrect binary data format in bind parameter 1`
```

here's my implementation:

```
    const where = Prisma.sql`WHERE ${searchConditions.join(' AND ')}`;
    const fetchCount = await prisma.$queryRaw`
    SELECT 
      COUNT(id)
    FROM
      table
    ${searchConditions.length > 0 ? where : Prisma.empty}
  `;
```

that will translate to the following in the prisma logs:

```
Query: 
    SELECT 
      COUNT(id)
    FROM
      table
    WHERE $1
   ["column = something"]
```

**SOLUTION**
I had to do a lot of rework to achieve what I want. Here's the idea behind it:

for every search condition you need to do the following:

```
let queryCondition = Prisma.empty;
    if (searchFilter) {
      const searchFilterCondition = Prisma.sql`column = ${searchFilter}`;

      queryCondition.sql.length > 0
        ? (queryCondition = Prisma.sql`${queryCondition} AND ${streamingUnitCondition}`)
        : (queryCondition = searchFilterCondition);
    }
```

afterwards in the final search query you can do something of this sort:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table ${queryCondition.sql.length > 0 ? Prisma.sql`WHERE ${queryCondition}` : Prisma.empty}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const where = Prisma.sql`where column = ${condition}`

const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT column FROM table ${condition ? where : Prisma.empty}`
```

Comment: thanks for you input. This worked when no condtions are passed, but once at least one parameter is given, an error is thrown. I updated my question with your suggestion. Can you take a look at it? thanks

Comment: In that case, you need to do something like [this](https://github.com/blakeembrey/sql-template-tag/issues/17).

Comment: Your first suggestion led me to the right response. I also followed the documentation https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access
so I'm gonna mark your response as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working version, using `Prima.join` :

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const searchConditions: Prisma.Sql[] = []
if (q) {
  searchConditions.push(Prisma.sql`column = ${q}`)
}
const where = searchConditions.length ? 
  Prisma.sql`where ${Prisma.join(searchConditions, ' and ')}` : 
  Prisma.empty

await prisma.$queryRaw(
  Prisma.sql`
    select *
    from table
    ${where}
    `
)
```