# Problem concatenating strings using JavaScript template literals

Tags: javascript, prisma, template-literals

I'm using the prisma.io library and having trouble working with template literals to do what I want. Maybe I don't understand them well enough.

I have this call:

```
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE active = ${activeSetting}`
```

And this works exactly the way I want.

However, I want to optionally append a string at the end without having to redo the full statement.

That is, I want something like:

```
let result;
if (orderBy === "ASC") {
  const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE active =
      ${activeSetting} ORDER BY ASC`
} else if {
  const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE active =
      ${activeSetting} ORDER BY DESC`
}
```

Basically, I don't want to have to have to complete statements that start with `const result = await`.  I realize this is a short example, but my problem is when I have fairly long SQL statements and I find myself doing a lot of cutting and pasting huge SQL which gets error prone.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do get that, but how do I deal with large queries where I build them conditionally depending on incoming variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle conditional prepared statements using prisma and postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67923628/283366)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm somewhat constrained by prisma.io. They mention queryRawUnsafe.  Is that the same as you are referring as prepare?  https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access

Comment: Oh, I see, it looks like `$queryRaw` takes care of that for you. Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Phil Yes, that question does help.  Still trying to grock what they are doing though.

Comment: @Pete: it's outside the scope of your question, but have you ruled out that you cannot make use of Prism's ORM rather than direct SQL statements?

Comment: Thanks @Alan.  I hope to use more of what Prisma offers.  Because of my lack of understanding I'm sure, it takes me 10x as long to figure out complex query scenarios in Prisma using there stuff then just piling in a bunch of SQL. Hopefully someday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I could have made a much bigger sql statement as well as concatenating bigger chunks of code and that would have made the problem more clear.  Thanks to @CertainPerformance and @Phil for the ideas.

Here is what I was really looking for that solves my bigger problem and still keeps me safe I'm pretty sure.

```
    const orderByAsc = Prisma.sql`ORDER BY ASC`;
    const orderByDesc = Prisma.sql`ORDER BY DESC`;
    const result =
      await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE active = ${activeSetting} ${
        orderBy === 'ASC' ? orderByAsc : orderByDesc
      }`;
```

And it also let's me put expressions in my sub clauses if need be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like so:

```js
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE active =
      ${activeSetting} ORDER BY ${orderBy === 'ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'}`
```

But it is better not to write raw SQL strings because you could leave yourself vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/sql-injection-sqli)